# How to allow several values in regexp submask

Tags: php

I want to pull some values out of string (in function)

```
if(!preg_match('/(.+)\.([0-9]*)x([0-9]*)(w|wr|r)?\.([^\.]+)$/', $filename, $matches))
    return false;

$file = $matches[1];
$width = $matches[2];
$height = $matches[3];
$set_watermark_or_nonconstrain = $matches[4];   // that's what I need to fix
$ext = $matches[5];
```

However, if I set string like {$image[0]->filename|resize:614:300:r} (Smarty), all goes well except that $set_watermark_or_nonconstrain is always 'w'. What do I need to set instead of w|wr|r to pull 'w', 'wr' or 'r' from this submask? Thanks!

Comment: This should be a string example "{$image[0]->filename|resize:614:300:r} (Smarty)" ? it doesn't work for this string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the string example you have given, the following expression does what you are looking for

```
   $string = '{$image[0]->filename|resize:614:300:r}';

   if(preg_match('/\{([^\|]+)\|[^:]+:(\d+):(\d+):([^}]+)/', $string, $m)){  
    echo 'm1: '.$m[1] ."<br />\n";
    echo 'm2: '.$m[2] ."<br />\n";
    echo 'm3: '.$m[3] ."<br />\n";
    echo 'm4: '.$m[4] ."<br />\n";
   }
```

Which produces the following ouput:

```
m1: $image[0]->filename
m2: 614
m3: 300
m4: r
```

Comment: Great thanks! Really a solution. Only I made error when wrote question, of course, preg_match analyzes only expression IN brackets. My fault, but that doesn't matter much.